# Android - Displaying Customized Toast in ListFragment throws an Error

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-toast

I didn't find any post to display customized toast in ListFragment. I have search all around.
Here is my customized xml file used to display a toast.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CC000000" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/course_deleted"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/delete"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_discard" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and a method that inflate this xml is:

```
private void delete(String course) {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this.getActivity());
    boolean status = db.deleteCourse(UNI, course);
    if (status) {
        view = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.custom_toast_layout_course_deleted,
                (ViewGroup) getActivity()
                        .findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout5));

        Toast toast = new Toast(getActivity());
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setView(view);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

But when my app runs it show this error:

```
11-13 09:48:13.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11052): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 09:48:13.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11052): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 09:48:13.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11052):    at ......delete(POKFragment.java:173)
11-13 09:48:13.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11052):    at ......access$0(POKFragment.java:161)
11-13 09:48:13.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11052):    at ......onClick(POKFragment.java:107)
```

and Line 173 is:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_layout_course_deleted,(ViewGroup) getActivityity().findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout5));
```

What is wrong in this code? It works fine for Activity but goes wrong with ListFragment.

Comment: is given xml is for Activity or your fragment?

Comment: its is custome xml which is inflated in Fragment to display a Toast.

Comment: Are you sure that your inflater is not null ?

Comment: the same code works fine if my class extends Activity but it goes wrong if my class extends ListFragment.

Comment: @AnishPanthi Have you checked my answer?

Comment: I have already called this in my onCreate(..) method: inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater(); and still its throwing NullPointerException

Comment: @AnishPanthi But have you changed the inflated view as per answer too?

Comment: yes I checked but it throws NullPointerException

Comment: Where is your `view`  object declared??

Comment: before onCreate(..) method called...

Comment: @AnishPanthi Is it returns in onCreateView() method in fragment then it will sure thows null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to change

```
 view = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.custom_toast_layout_course_deleted,
            null));
```

Also check that your `inflater` must not be null.

Answer (score 1):

I had posted just onCreate(..) method and the method where Toast is inflated.

```
    public class POKFragment extends ListFragment {

ListView list;
View rootView, view;

LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayAdapter<String> courseAdapter = null;
DatabaseHandler db = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pok, container, false);

    list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    int[] colors = { 0, 0xFF0072BC, 0 };
    list.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT, colors));
    list.setDividerHeight(3);

    courseAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, courses);
    setListAdapter(courseAdapter);
    courseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return rootView;
}
...............
...............
private void delete(String course) {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this.getActivity());
    boolean status = db.deleteCourse(UNI, course);
    if (status) {
        view = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.custom_toast_layout_course_deleted, null);

        Toast toast = new Toast(getActivity());
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setView(view);
        toast.show();
    }
}
...........
...........
}
```

Comment: Have a look at my ans and use it in combination with the answers from  Piyush Gupta.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you have this line

```
inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
```

in the onCreateView. It needs to be called after the onAttach(). SO do it in the onStart or in onActivityCreated.

Answer (score 0):

If your xml is inflated in your Fragment itself then no need to give any Activity parameter there.

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_layout_course_deleted,null);
```

Comment: I have already called this in my onCreate(..) method:
    inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
and still its throwing     
    NullPointerException

Comment: @AnishPanthi Move this line  inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater(); in delete() function.

Comment: bingo that works fine now... That is surprising... the same code works for Activity but not for ListFragment after making your change.. why so?

Comment: @AnishPanthi Because in Fragment view will be return only within the onCreateView() method.

Comment: @AnishPanthi I am surprised with your decision. Are you sure that you have accepted another answer compared to me? Great!!

Comment: that was mistake... changed the decision :D